# How to append to list without inserting a list within a list?

Tags: python, pandas, list, append

I have a dictionary with origin:row_rate as key-value pair. df2 is a pandas dataframe and as I iterate through the dataframe, I wanted to append the row_rate into the values of their corresponding origin key, if they key is already in dictionary. Else, I want to create new key for the origin and save the current row_rate and all other row_rates corresponding to that origin key.

I tried this:

```
data = {'Cuba': 999}

def append_rating(country, data):
    if country in data:
        return data[country]

for row in df2.itertuples(index=True):
    index = row.Index
    origin = row._9
    row_rate = row.Rating
    values = [append_rating(origin, data)]
    print(origin, values)
    values.append(row_rate)
    data[origin] = values
print(data)
```

this returns this:
`Congo [[[[[[[[[[None, 3.75], 3.5], 3.5], 3.5], 3.75], 3.0], 2.75], 3.25], 3.25]]`

And this...

```
def append_rating(country, data):
    if country in data:
        return data[country]
    else:
        return []
```

which returns this:
`Congo [[[[[[[[[[[], 3.75], 3.5], 3.5], 3.5], 3.75], 3.0], 2.75], 3.25], 3.25]]`

What I want is all elements of the list, resides in only one list. Something like this:
`Congo [3.75, 3.5, 3.5, 3.5, 3.75, 3.0, 2.75, 3.25, 3.25]`

Sorry for the basic question. Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Preliminary remarks

**First:** you want `data` to contain lists, so it is better to initialize `data['Cuba']` to the singleton list `[999]` rather than to the int `999`.

**Second:** you're going to have logic along the lines of:

> If `origin` is already in `data`, append to `data[origin]`; otherwise,
> create a new entry `data[origin]`.

When you have this kind of logic, you can use a `defaultdict` rather than a `dict`. `defaultdict` is a subclass of `dict` that automatically creates entries that don't exist when they are needed, and initialize them with a default value; in our case, the default value will be an empty list.

### Using a `defaultdict`

With these two things in mind, we can simplify your code:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

data = defaultdict(list, {'Cuba': [999]})

for row in df2.itertuples(index=True):
    index = row.Index
    origin = row._9
    row_rate = row.Rating
    data[origin].append(row_rate)

print(data)
```

### Using `if`/`else`

If we hadn't used a `defaultdict`, the code would be similar but slightly more complicated:

```py
data = {'Cuba': [999]}

for row in df2.itertuples(index=True):
    index = row.Index
    origin = row._9
    row_rate = row.Rating
    if origin in data:
        data[origin].append(row_rate)
    else:
        data[origin] = [row_rate]

print(data)
```

### Using `dict.get` with a default argument

Alternatively, we could have used `dict.get` with its default argument; this `dict` method is similar to your function `append_rating`:

```py
data = {'Cuba': [999]}

for row in df2.itertuples(index=True):
    index = row.Index
    origin = row._9
    row_rate = row.Rating
    data_origin = data.get(origin, [])
    data_origin.append(row_rate)
    data[origin] = data_origin

print(data)
```

Note how `data.get(origin, [])` is exactly equivalent to `append_rating(origin, data)`:

```py
data = {'Cuba': [999]}

def append_rating(country, data):
    if country in data:
        return data[country]
    else:
        return []

for row in df2.itertuples(index=True):
    index = row.Index
    origin = row._9
    row_rate = row.Rating
    data_origin = append_rating(origin, data)
    data_origin.append(row_rate)
    data[origin] = data_origin

print(data)
```

Note: I think the name of the function `append_rating` is not appropriate. "Append" usually means we're actively modifying something by adding an element. For instance, in python, `l.append(x)` modifies list `l` by adding element `x` to `l`. However, your function `append_rating(origin, data)` does not modify `data`. Instead, it looks up an entry in `data` and returns it if it exists. This is why it should better be called `get_rating` or `get_if_exists` or something similar. But actually this function already exists in python, it's `dict.get`.

### Useful documentation

- [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)
- [`dict.get`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=dict%20get#dict.get)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking for the `list.extend(other_list)` method.

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html

```py
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [4, 5, 6]

a.extend(b)

a == [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score -2):

You can simply use `list.extend()`